# How to draw an image with a softer color range?

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawing

I have implemented a custom `TreeListView` for .NET and I want to add `Ctrl+X / Ctrl+V` functionality.

I want that when the user cuts a node, the node image is rendered softer than usually, as the windows explorer does:

[image]

Someone could explain how to do it with a `System.Drawing.Image` in C#? I use `Graphics.DrawImage` to draw images, so I need a function to transform the icon.

Is there any built-in algorithm to do it? Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw a white rectangle on top that is partially transparent. Easier than re-calculating all the pixels.

Comment: The simplest solution is always the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the color of the image, I would just make the image more transparent. You could use the [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx) as mentioned in the other answers with a matrix that makes the alpha channel 50% or so.

```
float[][] colorMatrixElements = { 
   new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0.5f, 0},        // alpha scaling factor of 50%
   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(colorMatrixElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change brightness of the image.

I found some links [here](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Adjusting-Brightness-of-an-Image-in-C.aspx) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140825114946/http://bobpowell.net/image_contrast.aspx).

---

But if I were you, I would simplify it and just use a different image that I had modified externally instead of doing it programmatically.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba have a look please.

Comment: I can't do it since I load the images associated to the extensions through the OS.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx) class for examples also the [Recoloring Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7xw19wh.aspx) page linked from there. You should be able to find more info searching for `ColorMatrix` on both here and all of the internets.

Note that the `ColorMatrix` class works in the RGBA space so performing transformations on the colours to adjust brightness and saturation is not that straightforward. It's often easier to do this kind of stuff in the HSV space. In the RGBA space you might be best off simply adjusting the alpha channel (A) so that the colours appear fainter.

If you have only a small, finite set of icons then it's often easier just to manually make a second set of colour adjusted icons using your favourite Photoshop clone.